# why no-blocking node reduce I/O total time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There was a node tutorial point out:

> node is a no-blocking I/O system. if there were a task consuming time m, another task consumeing time n(m'<'n).then,the total consuming time wound be 'm+n' in a blocking I/O system.but it will be n in node.

However, since javascript is a single-thread language. I think it wouldn't reduce the time even the so-call event-loop there for the tasks, right?

Under the hood, is it all because node is using C/C++ multi-threads to accomplish this.

---

all right .My main confusion is I mess I/O consuming-time was included in javascript calculation .

Comment: So your question is if documentation is correct?

Comment: Under the hood I/O tasks don't run inside node. They run in other processes or even other servers in other countries/continents

Comment: nope,I ask this cause I don't understand it as a total beginner

Comment: @slebetman yeah.I understand a little bit, the I/O time is consumed outside program developed by node.the blocking system would just wait for the return.node would step over to the next

Comment: @John Ironically, this makes node behave in ways that is sometimes counter-intuitive. If you want to cache something large like a generated html page or an image node is much faster if you cache them to file than to RAM. This is because variable/object/array access is synchronous so reading a 1MB value from a variable will pause the interpreter while streaming a 1MB file from disk will not. Thus you can easily stream multiple 1MB files from disk in parallel but you will slow down trying to write a 1MB variable to a socket

Comment: can I think it as this: cache something to RAM is totally  by javascript to calculate . cache large files is hand it over to OS, or not OS,is C/C++ code to parse file,that's why it's  faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Javascript is a single threaded but with a non blocking IO implementation. The above line means something like this think you have to get a HTTP response from a server, which is a IO using the network interface of your computer, So while the HTTP response comes the thread is free (no calculations happens on your CPU, by means your CPU thread is free), so it can continue doing other tasks maybe rendering your page.

The only way that a Javascript thread is hanged is a higher execution rate. Think you are doing some kind of massive calculations. In this case yeah, your process is blocked. But this is not a IO (Input or Output).

So you are confused between IO non blocking and CPU thread blocking

Answer (score 1):

Node, basically won’t play the major role in reducing the time of executing the single task but it is like a parallel processing. That means it would not wait for the other task to complete and multiple tasks can be executed at time. The concept is as you known about the multiple threads executing at the same time to utilise maximum cpu and memory ( time in milli seconds ) so we will feel that all executed concurrently